# How to parse JSON response (python). The below is the result from POSTMAN. I want "displayvalue" to use internall for

Tags: python

The below is the response from `POSTMAN`. I want `"displayvalue"` where I can use internally for my project. I need a `JSON` parsing method (`python 2.7`) to get the `"displayValue"` (`"Digital Transformation in Higher Education"`).

```
"cells": [
    {
        "columnId": 3653592960788356,
        "value": "Digital Transformation in Higher Education",
        "displayValue": "Digital Transformation in Higher Education"
    },
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `__import__('json').loads(the_json_string)` ?

Comment: I tried several ways like decoded the value and printed, looped the value. Could you pls provide me the correct syntax:

Comment: @KrishnaaSukumaran, did any of your attempts include importing and using the [built-in `json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?